# I got an error after updating node using command line

Tags: node

I just updated my node and received this error message

```
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Files src/lib_stdlib_unix/tezos_stdlib_unix.cmxa
       and /Users/administrator/tezos/_opam/lib/lwt/lwt_unix.cmxa
       make inconsistent assumptions over implementation Lwt_log
```

Comment: can you edit the question to describe what you ran to get the above error?